# How to count all entires of recyclerview list in android app using Appium

Tags: android, node.js, selenium-webdriver, appium, ui-automation

In the app I'm automating using `appium+node.js`, the screen with Offers has `recyclerview` for offer list. Each cell is an image without any text on it.

I am getting the total count of offers through `API` call and want to assert that count by counting the total list entries.

[image]

Currently I am only able to get count of elements displayed on the screen(i.e 3 in this case).

How can I count each entry of this section and match that count with the total count of `API` result?

Comment: did you get any solution for this? Please update the answer if you have any

Comment: I solved this by 1. telling the dev to pass a unique id for each entry in content-desc of the layout 2. then scrolling the page and storing unique ids in a list and keep on scrolling till you stop getting unique ids(the logic is once you reach the end of the page and you scroll you will get the same id as there is nothing to scroll, so stop there)